# Why is Android Mobile SDK connect.iq broken?

Tags: android, mobile, connectiq

Downloaded Garmin Android Mobile SDK.
Unzipped it.
Copied it to Libs in my project.
The file looks like it has a vertical zip on the icon.
Unable to open and view the file in Studio.
Unable to get the instance of ConnectIQ object as Studio unable to resolve the symbol ConnectIQ which is therefore shown in red.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: If it shows a vertical zip, it's probably still compressed - is it a tar file? Have a look at the file extension

Comment: It has a jar file ext.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Mikkel.  We are both right.  The file is named connectiq.jar BUT it is not a jar file!  You have to unzip it and it is full of bloat including the connectiq.jar file itself.  How typically Garmin.